# Why SlingHttpServletRequest getAttribute returns null from Dispatcher

Tags: aem

I am setting the request attribute in Sling Filter as below

```
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)  {
    final SlingHttpServletRequest slingRequest = (SlingHttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    
    slingRequest.setAttribute("foo", "bar");
```

And Trying to get the value in Sling model

```
 request.getAttribute("foo"));
```

This returns null when opening the page from Dispatcher.

But when I open the it from Publish then it returns correctly.

Comment: How are you verifying if `request.getAtrribute("foo")` yields the expected, non-null value? Are you using the debugger and stopping at a breakpoint?

Comment: I have written logger to print the value